# asp.net grid color setting

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asp.net-controls

I have a gridview that is bind to the datatable. how to programmaticaly change the color of the 1-st column, after the binding has been done?

Comment: What do you mean by "after the binding?" If it's "after the binding" then the rendering has been completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it while binding is taking place in the RowDataBound Event.

Set the color of the cell in the 1st column in the event:

```
protected void gridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = Color.Red
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to handle the "OnRowCreated" event.  You can do this by adding to this Gridview declaration in the .aspx like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated" />
```

then you can refer to cells on a row by row basis - this will set the background color of the column to blue.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
}
```